# How to randomly assign values across a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as below:

```
df1.head()

cust_id   pd

a1       0.60
a2       0.26
a3       0.94
a4       0.44
a5       0.65
a6       0.88
```

I want to create a new column as `State` which can take 1 of the 4 values: NY, Florida, Cal, Michigan

I want to have random equal distribution of states across`cust_id`.

How can this be achieved in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this might be useful but you could try using [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id':['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6'], 'pd':[0.6,0.26,0.94,0.44,0.65,0.88]})
df
    cust_id    pd
0      a1     0.60
1      a2     0.26
2      a3     0.94
3      a4     0.44
4      a5     0.65
5      a6     0.88

states = ['NY', 'Florida', 'Cal', 'Michigan']
df['States'] = [ random.choice(states) for _ in range(len(df)) ]
df
      cust_id    pd      states
0      a1       0.60       Cal
1      a2       0.26   Florida
2      a3       0.94  Michigan
3      a4       0.44       Cal
4      a5       0.65   Florida
5      a6       0.88  Michigan
```

Comment: looks great...I will try this.Basically, I want to check the final distribution whether its uniform or some States are represented more (even if its randomly assigned).